# flexbox layout margin-bottom of the browser window

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to make a layout with flexbox model layout. I want to
    make full height of parent element, however I want some margin-bottom
    of the browser window. It does not matter how big screen is margin
    bottom remain same.

```
Many thanks and complete code.

https://jsfiddle.net/magtechpro/hu45ns64/2/
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: What does "I want some margin-bottom of the browser window" mean?

Answer (score -1):

make the bottom border colour the same as the page background - or Transparent. In the fiddle it won't look right but on the page it should.

```
.flexbg {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2rem auto;      
    height: 98vh;
}
```

Do your research for cross-browser support though.

Comment: I tried it does not work. .flexbg height does not expand with the browser height.
    https://jsfiddle.net/magtechpro/hu45ns64/5/